# How do I resize foremost window using AppleScriptObjC (such as NSWindow of Appkit)?

Tags: xcode, macos, nswindow, appkit

We can use AppleScript to resize the window easily if it is scriptable, however, I want to know whether NSWindow can do the same thing? Or something like NSWindow? I only found "Creating Windows" on https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nswindow, so I doubt of the feasibility of this idea.

Comment: `NSWindow` in AppKit can only control the windows in the current process (means an app can only control its own windows) regardless of using ObjC, Swift or AppleScriptObjC. In AppleScript the alternative for non-scriptable applications is GUI scripting via `System Events`

Answer (score 0):

Well if you make an AppleScript Objective C app with its own NSWindows you can control what they do from the script. So first make a property for the Window in the Script.

```
property theWindow : missing value
```

In the Interface Builder (the xib document with the Window) Link the Property `theWindow` to a window. (right click the delegate (the blue cube on the left) and drag the new property onto the window in the sidebar (don't drag it onto the windows view or it won't work))

The in the script you can tell the window what to do like change its size and location:

```
theWindow's setFrame_display_({{13, 14}, {23, 24}}, true)
```

This will set the windows size to 23 x 24 and its location (origin) to 13 x 14

(correct me if it is the other way round, I haven't used this for a while)